# How to create a wireframe / outline

Tags: mesh, wireframe

The user in the screenshot below has used blender to make the wireframe and effect. Can you tell me which tools and plugins he used?

[image]

Comment: I think it's just Wireframe modifier.

Comment: If you already know who made this, why not just ask him?

Answer (score 1):

That's probably done using [Freestyle](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/freestyle/index.html), which was made to create line drawings.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems some sort of curve object with a circle bevel, like this:

[image]

if you look carefully, it seems to cast shadows on itself, so I don't think it could be done with Freestyle. Or, maybe it's mixed with freestyle...